# How can I make new images between two images using MATLAB? The images are different cross sections of a spherical body

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I hope you are doing well.
I am quite new to MATLAB, and I am going to find a new image between two images using MATLAB.
The images are different cross sections of a spherical body.
Any idea how to do it?

[image: 1]

I only could find the median colour for each pixels of the two images.

Comment: so you want interpolation? or not?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank you for your reply. Yes, I want to interpolation but not about just color.

Comment: can you formulate that as a positive (you DO want... what?), instead of a negative (you don't want)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Actually, I want interpolation of the geometry. The images are two cross-section of a spherical tumor.

Comment: do you expect two slices to be enough to do that?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have 29 slices. My supervisor required me to generate 1 image between each 2 of them.

Comment: (we assume the images ar well registered) Interpolation is well understood on gray-scale images : in this case, just take, for each pixel, the midvalue between the graylevels in the first and the second image ; if there are three channels, for example Red Green Blue, do that on each of the channels. Afterwards, you will have maybe to use a smoothing filter, in order to reduce the noise...